# Excluding $tf folder in TFS 2015 - Copy and Publish Build Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to exclude $tf folder as part of artifact publishing using "Copy and Publish Artifacts" option as shown in the picture. But it always includes $tf folder and publishes all the files under this folder.

I tried this option, but no luck. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb22c23e-cb44-44d2-8170-ba5609e9a688/need-help-excluding-the-tf-folder-and-sub-items?forum=TFService

"Copy files" is not an option for publishing artifacts, so it would be better if there is any option to exclude the folder. 
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to publish the source code as an artifact? The build is tied to a changeset, and you can have it create a label on build completion if you need to be able to easily see what the source code looked like at the time of the build.

Comment: What's the result with my solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using **Copy Files** and **Publish Build Artifacts** tasks instead:

1. Copy Files: Source Folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory); Target Folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory);

Contents:

```
**\*
!$tf\**
!**\$tf\**
```

2. Publish Build Artifacts: Path to Publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Comment: I was using Copy and Publish Build Artifacts to perform the task, but didn't work.

Comment: @Yass Yes, doesn't work for me too, but it is deprecated, so using copy files and publish build artifacts tasks instead.